# How to change StatusBar color in Light and Dark Material 3 Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack, android-theme, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I provide my own color to change statusbar color in my app but it don't work in Material 3.
Here is the default Light and Dark colors in Theme.kt file:

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)
private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40
)
```

In App Theme composable function `window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()` I change the primary color also but it won't work.

Comment: Hey @Fatiq you have to make dynamicColor: Boolean = false in Theme Parameter

Answer (score 1):

Hi there，you can do like this:

```html
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb() // change color status bar here
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Newly created project, based on material3, please type your Theme.kt
Code, just **delete** `window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()`

Then you can still **modify** the color of the status bar and navigation bar through `rememberSystemUiController`